# Splitting a string between two reoccurring characters

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic values in a variables, each separated with [ and ] e.g.

```
var data="[Continuing] [Returning] "; or
var data="[ACCT_BBA] "; or
var data="[12001] [12009] [21077] [13880] ";
var data="[13880] ";
```

Is there a way to use the split function to extract the values between the [ and the ] from above?

```
var arr= data.split("<what goes here?>");
```

e.g. on the last example to retrieve: 12001, 12009, 21077, 13880

Comment: what do you want extracted exactly?

Comment: I think what OP wants to archieve is to get values between the braces
e.g. 
`var data="[Continuing] [Returning]";` 
to
`var values = ["Continuing", "Returning"];`
You can archieve this using regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data.slice(1, -2).split("] [")
```

should do the job, or if your start and end are uncertain maybe

```
data.replace(/^\s*\[|\]\s*$/g, "").split("] [")
```

Alternatively, if you need something more complex, the choice is usually [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a global regex, or building your own parser if you need to handle arbitrarily nested structures.

Comment: Very nice. And faster than asenovm's answer which has a bug.

Comment: partially working. the last value extracted still has a ]. from the tests I've ran, mplungjan solution is working

Comment: @D.Rattansingh: That would suggest your `data` doesn't end in `]`. Maybe there's a space left? If you need to cope with such, you might want to use `.replace(/^\s*\[|\]\s*$/g, "")` instead of simply `slice`ing off the first and last character.

Comment: yes, sorry, i now checked, there is a space left at end of string

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
data.split('] [').map(function (item) { return item.replace("]", "").replace("[", "")})
```

like this:

```js
    //var data="[Continuing] [Returning]";
    // var data="[ACCT_BBA]"; 
    var data="[12001] [12009] [21077] [13880]";

    var res = data.split('] [').map(function (item) { return item.replace("]", "").replace("[", "")})
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: This would fail on this simple case : `[[one]] [[two]]` which would not have any `[` or `]` but should.  You need to apply the replace to the first character of the first element and the last character of the last element -- not use map()

Comment: @Hogan that is however not a usecase given

Comment: @mplungjan - see Bergi's answer.  The OP intent is clear... don't change stuff inside the brackets (at least that is what I would assume after reading requirements for 30 years or so.

Comment: @D.Rattansingh: It does however leave the trailing space(s) in the last value

Answer (score 1):

What about `data.match(/\[(\w+)\]/g).map(e => e.slice(1, -1))`

And you can replace `\w` with the scope of character, like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you do:

```
var data="[12001] [12009] [21077] [13880]";

var arr = data.split(" ");

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace('[','');
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(']','');
}
console.log(arr);
```

just an example, very basic one.